# Sending a message from a node to its neighboors

Tags: c++, omnet++

I got a network of nodes where i want to send a message from the node identified by the ID 401 to its neighbors. Below is the code i used:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    cMessage *copy = msg->dup();
    send(copy, "out", i);
}
delete msg;
```

Below is the error message that I got

```
<!> Error in module (Node) topo. nd[401] (id=404) during network initialization: send()/sendDelayed(): Gate index 0 out of range when accessing vector gate `out[]' with size 0.
```

Comment: Not knowing much about Omnet++ (nothing at all, really) it looks like you have a memory leak in that loop, as you don't delete the duplicates you seem to be creating.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: duplicates of a message must not be deleted *here* because it will be overtaken by module which *receives* it, and that  module has to delete this duplicate (after using it).

Answer (score 3):

This error means that:

- gate `out` was declared in `NED` file as a vector (probably this way: `output out[];`)
- gate `out` has not been connected to any other nodes (i.e. it has size equal to 0)

What you should do is to connect gate `out` of your node to an input gate of every other node.
Moreover, I suggest checking size of `out` vector in for loop, for example:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < gate("out", 0)->getVectorSize(); ++i) {
       // ...
    }
```

Note: the above code will properly work only if at least one port of `out` is connected.

Comment: I tried it and it worked. I appreciate your help @JerzyD